# What limits the number of skylights you can put in a room?

Tags: roof

I am thinking of putting skylights in my kitchen between the trusses in the attic. Let's say my kitchen is below 5 trusses, giving me 4 spaces where I can put a skylight. Is there any structural consideration that would keep me from putting a skylight in *each* of the four spaces?

I know I would probably lose more heat through the winter. But we live in Seattle and with the rain we get, it's nice to have as much sunlight in the house as you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no structural reason why you cannot put skylights between each truss.

As long as you don't interfere with the trusses themselves, all you're doing is replacing the weight of the roof and shingles for the weight of the skylights.

You may, however, find that the skylights themselves make the idea difficult, as they are likely to have fairly wide flanges on either side to help avoid water penetration.  Those flanges are likely to get in each others way for a side-by-side install.

However, in a side-by-side install, you could cut them down and set one on top of the other, just be sure to very fully seal the entire seam where the flanges are cut.

Answer (score 2):

Check your town's building code; some towns only permit the roof penetration to be so large because skylights are energy-inefficient.  The R-value of a skylight is probably less than the R-value of your roof.  So expect heat loss or too much heat.